# Junit EntityManager NullPointerException with App Engine 1.7 Upgrade

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a number of JUnit tests in my project that test my DataStore services. For the past two years, they've been working just fine and I've been able to successfully insert, query, and delete entities through unit tests. A couple of days ago I upgraded to App Engine 1.7 and all of a sudden all of my tests throw a NullPointerException because

Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional") returns null. My persistence.xml file contains the following configuration which like I said, has worked perfectly up until the upgrade.

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider> 
    <properties> 
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/> 
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/> 
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/> 
    </properties> 
</persistence-unit>
```

Also, I walked through the GAE testing setup article and I do have all of the required jar files on my class path. Any idea what could have changed in the upgrade?

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortuntaley there's not really a stack track to print. Here's the exact code that fails: NullPointerException : EntityManager entityManager = EMF.get().createEntityManager(); Obviously the null pointer is from EMF.get() which internally is calling Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was an Eclipse or Google Eclipse plugin issue. In the Project > Properties the GAE setting was checked. I even checked and unchecked it to make sure it was turned on. And in fact run and debug modes would work perfectly but the JUnit tests would fail. I just attempted to fix the issue again and I noticed that both the GWT and GAE libraries were missing from the Java path despite the fact that the check boxes in the Google settings were checked. Very weird but now the Junit tests work.